Sort by two columns where first is already sorted in pandas
I have a kind of big DataFrame, and therefore it can't be sorted on O(n²). I want to sort by two columns, and one of those columns is already sorted.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [ 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'col2': [ 'c', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'f']
})
df2 = sort_ordered(df, 'col1', 'col2')
assert df2.equals(df.sort_values(['col1', 'col2']))

How can I sort by those two columns, assuming that the first column is already sorted?.
That way, as only the elements in the second column need to be sorted "per group", the complexity would be O(n*k²) worst case or O(n(klog k)) in average, where k is the number of elements in each "partition" of the first column. In this case, $k$ is a number between 1 to 12, making the proposed solution almost linear, instead of worst-case quadratic.
I provide the pseudocode of an iterative approach:
wstart = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
  if df.iloc[i]['col1'] != df.iloc[wstart]['col1']:
    wstart = i
    df.iloc[wstart:i] = df.iloc[wstart:i].sort_values('col2')


Sorting is generally n log n, not n^2. The number of columns in the key doesn't affect this.

This question is similar to: pandas groupby, then sort within groups. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Barmar sorting is, in the worst case, n^2. Nevertheless, n*10 is way less than nlog n in my case.

How do you get n*k? it will be k * (n^2) where n is the average size of each partition.

@AndrewYim That question asks about sorting the results.

@Bamar Yeah, sorry, I forgot the ^2. I updated the question because in sorting using the average case is way more common than the worst case.

Could any of you explain whether there would be any advantage of considering that the first column is already sorted?

@SuramuthuR It means instead of sorting the whole DataFrame twice (sorta), you only have to sort it once (sorta).

@David Davó: some sorting algorithms guarantee O(n log n) even in worse case (e.g. merge sort)

Premature optimization is not a good strategy
On average, sorting is O(n*logn). You might improve the complexity by sorting per group, but is it worth it in terms of absolute timings?
Let's compare with real data. Pandas can realistically handle DataFrames up to about billion rows. Here I'll go up to ~500M.
To generate the dataset, we'll produce N rows, with sorted groups of 10 values in col1, and random integers in col2:
def init(N):
    return pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.arange(N)//10,
                         'col2': np.random.randint(0, 20, N)
                        })

We have two strategies, sorting by the two columns and sorting per group:
# sort by both columns
df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'])

# sort by group, only on col2
(df.groupby('col1', sort=False, group_keys=False)[list(df)]
   .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='col2'))
)

# variant using groupby.transform
df.assign(col2=df.groupby('col1', sort=False)['col2'].transform(np.sort))

groupby is a slow operation, especially with many small groups. Unsurprisingly a normal sort is much faster (about 300 times):

If we try to plot a n*log(n) curve:

groupby.transform is not much better:

Looks like sticking to sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2']) is the most efficient after all.

You explained nicely. Though I didn't compare with groupby, This was the point I meant in my comments. There can't be much difference in the efficiency between directly sorting with sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2']) and presorting  col1 and and then sorting with sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2']). Infact, later will be more efficient than the former. So, my point is: we don't need to be bothered about whether col1 is presorted or not. Instead sort with sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2']). I tried to explain in the comments. As there were 4 downvotes in my answer, I deleted. Good work!

I failed to explain properly -even in my comments. If you can access the deleted answer of mine and its comments, Kindly read.

The only convenience in presorting is 'more comfortness in viewing'. We can't expect anything more than this.

Being a timeseries, there's no cost in sorting by col1, it has been always sorted. I have updated the answer with a pseudocode for an iterative approach.

My dataset is split between multiple files. I reached a compromise by sorting each file individually before loading them.

@DavidDavó can you estimate how long this took in comparison to the complete sorting after loading?

I just shutted down the process after an hour. The other advantage is that If I go file by file I can kind of get the progress.

Yes, try:
df.assign(col2=df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(np.sort))

Output:
   col1 col2
0     0    a
1     0    c
2     1    b
3     2    e
4     2    f
5     2    h


If you don't use sort=False in groupby you will still sort on "col1", that said, it's actually much slower that a simple sort_values (see my comparison).

@mozway Yep, I forgot to turn off the sort parameter in groupby.  Nice catch.
